# How to assign foreign key of parent_id to a post route when creating a new child

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

when a parent sign into the app there is a form where you can add a child. I'm trying to assign the foreign key to the parent that is adding a child but not too sure exactly how to do this. I tried assign the foreign key to "parent_id" then calling it in the post but I get this error:

Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Field 'ParentId' doesn't have a default value

This is my model for a child:

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Child = sequelize.define("Child", {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  });

  Child.associate = function(models) {
      Child.belongsTo(models.Parent, {
      foreignKey: "parent_id"
    });
  };

  return Child;
}
```

This is the routes for the "add child" form

```
app.get("/addChild", function (req, res) {
    res.render("addChild");
  });

app.post("/addChild", function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    db.Child.create({
      name: req.body.childName,
      foreignKey: req.body.parent_id 
    }).then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      res.json(data);
    });
  });
```

I am using this in my index.js. dialect:mysql and the "mysql2": "^1.5.2"

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var basename = path.basename(module.filename);
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
var db = {};

if (config.use_env_variable) {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
} else {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, 
config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function (file) {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && 
(file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(function (file) {
    var model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
     db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function (modelName) {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
   }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Comment: did you try replacing `foreignKey` in your `create` function with `parent_id` ?

Comment: So that it looks like this ---- parent_id: req.body.parent_id? I get the same error.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. Would I have have to do any associations in my parent model like I did in the child? Like a hasMany?

Comment: If you can, try just `Child.belongsTo(models.Parent)` without using `foreignKey` then in `create`: `ParentId: req.body.parent_id`. If this doesn't work, there is a deeper error somewhere that needs to be resolved.

Comment: So do you mean like so:    app.post("/addChild", function (req, res) {

    db.Child.create({
      name: req.body.childName,
      ParentId: req.body.parent_id
    }).then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      res.json(data);
    });
  });

Comment: Yes, given that you defined the association as `Child.belongsTo(models.Parent)`

Comment: Okay, I may has a different issue then. That doesn't work

Comment: Can you edit your question to include which sequelize version and which dialect you're using? I have a working example on my machine using postgres pg@7.4.1 and sequelize@4.35.2

The exact error message you're getting is virtually undocumented and the only info I could find was a primary key not being autoincremented. It makes me think there's an issue with how sequelize is communicating with your database. [See what I mean here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/installation/usage.html#dialects)

Comment: I've added the index.js page when mysql is connecting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166373/discussion-between-vapurrmaid-and-stacy-areas).

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to assign the foreign key to the parent that is adding a child but not too sure exactly how to do this

`foreignKey` in `create` should be `parent_id`.
Also ensure that `foreignKey` is listed in the Parent model.

Here's a minimal example:

parent.js:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var Parent = sequelize.define('Parent', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {})
  Parent.associate = function (models) {
    Parent.hasMany(models.Child, {
      foreignKey: 'parent_id' // note foreignKey added
    })
  }

  return Parent
}
```

child.js:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var Child = sequelize.define('Child', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {})
  Child.associate = function (models) {
    Child.belongsTo(models.Parent, {
      foreignKey: 'parent_id'
    })
  }
  return Child
}
```

Working Spec:

```
const httpMocks = require('node-mocks-http')
const assert = require('assert')
const db = require('../models')

// mocking your /addChild route handler
async function AddChild (req, res, next) {
  const child = await db.Child.create({
    name: req.body.childName,
    parent_id: req.body.parent_id  // parent_id not foreignKey
  })

  res.send(child.toJSON())
}
.
.
.
describe('Test Case', function () {
    it('Associates', async function () {
      const parent = await db.Parent.create({ name: 'Parent' })

      // mock request with body
      const req = httpMocks.createRequest({
        body: {
          childName: 'child',
          parent_id: parent.id
        }
      })

      let res = httpMocks.createResponse()
      await AddChild(req, res)
      assert(res._getData().parent_id === parent.id)

      // ensure association exists as expected
      await parent.reload({
        include: [{
          model: db.Child
        }]
      })
      assert(parent.Children[0].name === 'child')
    })
  })
})
```